# If multiple subscribers block on a core.async channel, is the order in which they take the values out when they come guaranteed?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, clojure, core.async

Given an unbuffered `core.async` channel (or buffered, it shouldn't really matter), if multiple subscribers all wait on the channel, what is the order in which they take out the incoming messages? For example

```
(take! ch #(println "callback " 1 " got value " %))
(Thread/sleep 1000)
(take! ch #(println "callback " 2 " got value " %))
(Thread/sleep 1000)
(take! ch #(println "callback " 3 " got value " %))
(Thread/sleep 1000)

(put! ch 'a)
(put! ch 'b)
(put! ch 'c)
```

It seems that the order in this case is always `1 a`, `2 b`, `3 c`, but I'm not sure if this is guaranteed, or if I'm just getting lucky? The `Thread/sleep` is added only to make sure that the subscribers subscribe in the order `1 2 3`.

**If the ordering is guaranteed in this case, are there any other cases with `core.async`, where the order of putting/taking things out of a channel is random?** I remember hearing somewhere, that some part of `core.async` intentionally introduces randomess to avoid users depending on some ordering of events, but I'm not sure if this was in relation to `put!` and `take!`.

The reasony why I'm asking this is because I wanted to use `core.async` as a synchronization mechanism, since it's rather simple to use. But in order to do that, I need to know if it'd actually synchronize anything, or introduce more randomness and non-determinism.

Comment: Yes it's en-queued and the order is guaranteed. `alts!` adds some non-determinism to avoid only draining one channel.

Answer (score -1):

The docstrings to `take!` and `put!` make it explicitly clear that these are asynchronous operations, hence the API does not promise any order.

You have to either pass continuations to `take!` and `put!` or use the synchronous equivalents `<!!`/`>!!` (`<!`/`>!` in a `go` block).

Comment: This is not what I was asking. Just because they're asynchronous doesn't mean that there's no guarantee on the channel. I can synchronize `take!` and `put!` to run in order (via promises or whatever), but that still doesn't answer the fundamental question, which is: **if there are multiple producers or subscribers already blocking on a channel, which one goes first?** I'm not asking about the ordering in which `take!` and `put!` are executed, but about the ordering in which they unblock. For the sake of the question, consider I already know the order in which they started blocking.

Comment: Exactly because they are asynchronous operations you can't know when or in which order they are going to be executed. Thus, based on the use of them, any assumptions about channel queues, blocking or unblocking order can't hold anyway.

Comment: From a cursory glance at the source, both `<!!` and `take!` are implemented in terms of `clojure.core.async.impl.protocols/take!`, so it would appear that if the behavior of `<!!` guarantees the order of unblocking, then so does the behavior of `take!`.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin I think you're still looking at it from a different point of view. Yes, you can't generally know the order in which the asynchronous operations will publish. But that's not what I'm asking. The question was that _if the order of publishers is guaranteed, in what order do the subscribers take out the value?_ The reason why I asked that is because `<!!` and `<!` would have the same ordering semantics, since it is a question about the ordering properties of the channel itself, not about the implementation of `put!`, or any other function that manipulates channels.

Comment: @erikprice thanks! I'll take a look at the source, I guess there's no other way of figuring this out anyway.

Comment: @erikprice Your conclusion is wrong. In the blocking implementations continuations are used to establish order, not invocation order. E. g. the `<!!` implementation passes continuation to `take!` to deliver a blocking promise. It's the same with the other operations and code generated by the go macro.

Comment: @JakubArnold Also you can't know the order in which asynchronous operations will subscribe. Neither the order of puts nor the order of takes is guaranteed by the asynchronous API of core.async. This fact defeats all your follow-up questions that are built on different assumptions. If you are asking about the blocking part of core.asyncs API, you should use the blocking ops in your code examples.